# Is there a way to get a node's dimensions without displaying it in the Node Editor?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

The aim of the question is to calculate a node tree layout for a generated node tree.

Nodes have `height`, `width` and `dimensions`.

It seems that `dimensions` corresponds to some default size and that `height` and `width` to the currently displayed dimensions. But these last two are not set until the node is effectively displayed somewhere in the editor (or am I wrong?).

But if you want to generate a node layout for a material or a node tree which is itself generated and which is not displayed for now, is it possible to get the `dimensions`? If yes, how?

We can:

```
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
```

to force a layout calculation. But this works only when the node tree is displayed in the Node Editor (at least it seems to be the case).

How can we get the 'future' default dimensions so that a node tree layout could be calculated?

**Edit: Some extra details**

When creating a node tree, it is not displayed until it is used (instantiated) in a material and opened for editing.

In this case,

- `width` and `height` are some default values: 140 and 100
- `dimensions` is a `Vector(0.0000, 0.0000)`

I've experimented and found that these values are updated when the node is displayed (and `bpy.ops.wm.redraw()` is called). So that typically, the Principled and Diffuse shader nodes do not end up having the same dimensions.
But before that, the dimension values are as given above.

The complete code is hard to share here, but here are some basic snippets:

Creating a node tree (node group) is:

```
node_group = node_groups.new( node_group_name, 'ShaderNodeTree' )
```

Creating a material is:

```
material = materials.new( material_name )
```

Creating a node in both cases:

```
self.internal_node = node_tree_nodes.new( type = self.name )
```

But once the data is created, there are two cases:

The node tree is displayed in a view and

```
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
```

can be use to 'force' a layout update and get the dimensions (if this `bpy.ops` is not called `height`, `width`, and `dimensions` are not updated).

Or the node tree (`bpy.data.node_groups` typically) is not displayed and I can't find a way to retrieve the 'future displayed' dimensions.

Comment: Can you give a little more info about what you're doing? As soon as I create a node with `node_tree.nodes.new('nodeType')` it adds the node to the node tree anyway. How are you creating nodes but *not* displaying them?

Comment: @RayMairlot, typically it's the case when creating a node tree which is not displayed until an instance of it is linked to a material. Will add code samples to explain better.

Comment: @RayMairlot, the node trees or materials are correctly created (and can be used), this is only a layout problem.

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks for the edit.

Comment: My guess is that the values aren't hard coded because the size the node displays at is dependant on the theme settings and the interface display size/dpi (`ui_scale` in 2.79 preferences). Changing the display size causes the `dimensions` to change. Maybe there's a way of combining these values with the `dimensions` to arrive at the final size.

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks. I think combining ui_scale with the count of the inputs, outputs and params should do it or at least will give a good enough approximation for most of nodes. Will try it when possible.

Comment: @RayMairlot, FYI, ui_scale does not change the height, width or dimensions of the node. Will use empiric approach 24 * (inputs + outputs + parameters + 1 for title) if not better way given as answer.

Comment: I can't tell you anything apart from what I tested; changing `ui_scale` produced drastically different values for the dimensions (in 2.79).

Comment: @RayMairlot, sorry, effectively you are right (my test was bad). But I think that dimension are the rendered dimensions (and so scale counts). But setting location seems to be scale independent.